# How do I prove that $\Phi(x)=\left(||x||,\frac{x}{||x||}\right)$ is a homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Folland-Real analysis p.77

Define $\Phi(x)=\left(||x||,\frac{x}{||x||}\right)$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$

How do I prove that $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} \rightarrow (0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ is a homeomorphism?

More over which norm $||\bullet||$ is it in the definition of $\Phi$? 2-norm? max-norm? arbitrary norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm is usually the Euclidean norm, i.e. the $2$-norm. But you can use any norm as long as you also define $S^{n}$ to be the sphere with respect to that norm.

Now what is a homeomorphism? A continuous, bijective map whose inverse is continuous.

Is $\Phi$ continuous? Yes, because $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous, and quotients are continuous as long as the denominator is non-vanishing.

Is $\Phi$ bijective? Yes, its inverse is given by $\Psi:(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$, $(x,z)\mapsto x\cdot z$.

Is the inverse continuous? Yes, because it is the product of two continuous functions.

Therefore, $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Is an arbitary $||\bullet||$ continuous under the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, it is. This follows from the reverse triangle inequality: $| \|x_n\|-\|x\| | \le \|x_n-x\| \rightarrow 0$. @Number8

Comment: Isn't $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||x_n-x|| = 0$ assuming that $||\bullet||$ is continuous..?

Comment: No, that is just continuity at $0$, which is obvious (why?).

Comment: Yes. This is because all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent! @Number8

Comment: I have only learned that max-norm and p-norm induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. And the continuity at 0 is not obvious to me.. would you please explain? thank you

Comment: @Number8 Look [here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/course/math561_spring2011/norm_equiv.pdf) for a proof that all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent. Do you understand how that implies continuity at $0$?

Comment: This is simply amazing.. I cannot believe why Munkres-Topology only introduces equivalence of max-norm and p-norm.. Thank you